# Animated Gradient Node?

Tags: animation, node-editor, shaders, light, procedural

I'm working on a knob with some LEDs around it.
When the knob is all the way at 0-position only the top and bottom LEDs are on and when all the way to the right 100% all the LEDs will be on.

(the LEDs are just an image texture with some bump. With one node of a turned-off LED and one node of a LED material that is glowing.)

The way I'm planning on animating this effect is to have a *Gradient* node controlling the mix fac of a *Mix* node. My question is how do I get the gradient "butterfly pattern" of the mix fac?

- Pic 1, the knob at 0, top and bottom LEDs are on
- Pic 2, the knob at 50%
- Pic 3, the way the knob looks.

[image]

Comment: I think with the gradient texure and some math you should be able to do it. Did you tried that?

Comment: Do you want your LEDs to light up one at a time, or do you want the fade?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and is [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing)

Comment: didn't mean to offend anyone with capital letters, will only use small caps from now on. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if i understood the request correctly, but that's the result (don't know if I'm allowed to post gifs):
[image]

[image]

And that's the nodes: [image]

Comment: As you can see top two rows are almost identical except X and Y are multiplied by -1. Maybe there's a more beautiful way how to reach  the symmetry, but I'm lazy :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this look perfect, will try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: This node setup works beautifully but is there a way to get a sire gradient from black to white? right now each led light up, but with a larger gradient I think I could get a more feathered look where the surrounding led of the active led is also slightly affected by the light. which of the math nodes do I use to control that?

Comment: Looks like you should change subtraction node to power: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTRCZ.png
And by the way, you can get rid of multiplication of X and Y by -1 with using vector absolute

Comment: thank you once again, you are the man!

Comment: You're welcome :)
There's wrong screenshot in the comment above. Fixed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcEhO.jpg

Answer (score 6):

You can get a gradient in all quarters, from 0.75 at North and South, to 0.5 at East and West, by using the absolute of X and Y as the texture-space for a *Gradient > Radial* node. And you can map that to something more convenient using a *Map Range* node.

[image]

Here, the range is used to produce a basic mask, whose extent is driven by the Z rotation of another object. You could multiply the mask with whatever color-gradient you wanted to put in it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could I be so lazy to request a _"Download the blend"_?

Comment: @batFINGER .... Done.

Comment: Wow that's clever! Thank you guys